# How to visualize point movements across multiple plots using Manipulate or something similar?

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate, visualization

I have the following three plots:

```
fx = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
fy = Table[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
plot1 = ListPlot[fx, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "fx"}];
plot2 = ListPlot[fy, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "fy"}];
plot3 = ListPlot[Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}], 
   Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"fx", "fy"}];
```

[image]
On `plot1` and `plot2`, each pair of points `{t, fx}` and `{t, fy}` corresponds to a point `{fx, fy}` on `plot3`. I would like to find a way to visualize the movement of these three points on the three plots. Specifically, when I move a point on `plot3`, I want the corresponding points on `plot1` and `plot2` to move accordingly.
I believe this task could be accomplished using `Manipulate` or a similar approach, but I am unsure of how to begin.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
fx = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/64}];
fy = Table[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/64}];
fxy = Transpose[#[[All, 2]] & /@ {fx, fy}];
```

Transform the coordinates in `fx` and `fy`:

```
translateScale[offset_ : 2, s_ : 1] := # Threaded[{s/2, 1}] + 
  Threaded[{offset, 0}] &;

cx = translateScale[] @ fx;
cy = Map[Reverse] @ translateScale[] @ fy;
```

Using `AxisObject` construct custom axes to be used with rotated/translated graphics primitives for `fx` and `fy`:

```
axes[offset_ : 2, s_ : 1] :=
 {AxisObject[Line[# /@ {{offset, 0}, {offset + s Pi, 0}}], {0, 2 Pi}, 
     TickLengths -> {.05, .025}, 
     TickLabels -> {Prepend[""]@Rest@Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2]}, 
     TickPositions -> {{Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2]}, {Pi/4}}, 
     AxisLabel -> Style[" θ", 14]],
    AxisObject[Line[# /@ {{offset, -1}, {offset, 1}}], {-1, 1}, 
     TickLengths -> {.05, .025}, TickLabels -> {Range[-1, 1, 1/2]}, 
     TickPositions -> {{1/2}, {1/4}}, 
     AxisLabel -> Placed[Style[
       # /. {Identity -> HoldForm[Sin[θ]], _ ->  HoldForm[Sin[2 θ]]}, 14],
       # /. {Identity -> {.5, -1}, _ -> Center}], 
     RotateLabel -> "Parallel"]} & /@ {Identity, Reverse}
```

Construct graphics primitives using the transformed coordinates:

```
plots[i_Integer] := ListLinePlot[{fxy, cx, cy}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin],
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 10, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Epilog -> {axes[], 
    First @ ListLinePlot[{fxy[[;; i]], cx[[;; i]], cy[[;; i]]}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thick],
    Text[Style["θ : " <> ToString[fx[[i, 1]], StandardForm], 16], 
      Scaled[{2/3, 2/3}], Center],
    AbsolutePointSize@10, 
    MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], Point @ #} &]@
     {fxy[[i]], cx[[i]], cy[[i]]},
    EdgeForm[Dashed], Opacity[.1, Yellow], 
    Polygon[{fxy[[i]], cx[[i]], cy[[i]]}]}]
```

Use `plots` with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[plots @ i,
  {{i, 5, "index"}, 1, Length @ fx, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

The animation above is produced using:

```
frames = Table[plots @ i, {i, 1, Length@fx}];;

Export["frames1.gif", frames]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 SetOptions[ParametricPlot,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]]];
 Legended[
  Column[{
    ParametricPlot[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"t", "fx"}),
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
     Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8],
       ColorData["Rainbow"][tv/(2 Pi)],
       Point[{tv, Sin[tv]}]}],
    ParametricPlot[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"t", "fy"}),
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
     Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
       ColorData["Rainbow"][tv/(2 Pi)],
       Point[{tv, Sin[2 tv]}]}],
    ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"fx", "fy"}),
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
     Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
       ColorData["Rainbow"][tv/(2 Pi)],
       Point[{Sin[tv], Sin[2 tv]}]}]}],
  Framed[
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 2 Pi}},
    LegendLabel -> Style["t", 14]],
   RoundingRadius -> 10]],
 {{tv, 0, "t"}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Manipulate[
 {ListPlot[fx, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "fx"}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.05], Point[{x, Sin[x]}]}],
  ListPlot[fy, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "fy"}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.05], Point[{x, Sin[2 x]}]}],
  ListPlot[Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}], Joined -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"fx", "fy"}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.05], Point[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x]}]}]}
 , {x, .0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Here we only use the discrete data, does not depend on the function `Sin[t]` and `Sin[2t]`.

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow@{Show[plot1, 
    Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Orange, Point@fx[[i]]}]], 
   Show[plot2, 
    Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Orange, Point@fy[[i]]}]], 
   Show[plot3, 
    Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Orange, 
      Point@Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}][[i]]}]]}, {i, 1, 
  Length@fx, 1}]
```

[image]

- We rotate -90 Degree of the graph `fx` to illustrate the co-relationship between `fx,fy` and `fxy`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
fx = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
fy = Table[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];

plotx = ListPlot[Reverse[fx, 2], Joined -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> Reverse@{"t", "fx"}];
ploty = ListPlot[fy, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "fy"}];
plotxy = 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}], Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"fx", "fy"}]; 
Manipulate[
 Grid@{{Show[plotxy, 
     Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, 
       Point@Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}][[i]]}]], 
    Show[ploty, 
     Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Magenta, 
       Point@fy[[i]]}]]}, {Show[plotx, 
     Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Magenta, 
       Point@Reverse@fx[[i]]}]]}}, {i, 1, Length@fx, 1}]
```

[image]